# How to send an image with Unity through a c# soap web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to send an image (and other field) using Unity and a web service.

This is my Unity c# client code :

```
 byte[] photoBytes = ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG( myObject.GetPhotoTexture(), 90);
     WWWForm form2= new WWWForm();
     form2.AddField("field1", field1);
     form2.AddField("field2", field2);
     if (photoBytes != null)
          {
             form2.AddBinaryData("photoBytes", photoBytes,FrameID.ToString() + ".jpg");
          }    
     string url = gsStaticClassManager.WEBSERVICE_URL + "UploadJustPhoto";
     WWW www = new WWW(url, form2);
     yield return www;
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        Debug.Log(www.error);
```

And this is my Web Service

```
[WebMethod]
public string UploadJustPhoto(string guid, int frameID, byte[] photoBytes)
{
    try
    {
        if (photoBytes != null)
        {                  
            string completeFileName = frameID + ".jpg";

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photoBytes);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(completeFileName, FileMode.Create);
            ms.WriteTo(fs);

            // clean up
            ms.Close();
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();

            return "OK";
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "KO";
    }

    return "KO";
}
```

I got always "HTTP 500 Error".

What can be the cause ?

Thanks

**EDIT:  I found following specific error:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: multipart/form-data; boundary=&quot;ANX8OOvdTQP97L1wHRXlndHJH9pnuLM8cWVzv13j&quot;.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Comment: Where in unity are you populating photoBytes

Comment: I've updated code: byte[] photoBytes = ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG( myObject.GetPhotoTexture(), 90);  ... GetPhotoTexture return a Texture

Comment: if you use a normal webform to send to the URL does it work? does the behavior change if you use `form2.AddBinaryData("photoBytes", photoBytes,FrameID.ToString() + ".jpg","text/pain");` ?  PS what is the error reported on the webserver

Comment: Did you try to use a [UnitywebRequest.Post](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html) instead of `WWW` (obsolete) ? Btw why do you also return "OK" if the `photoBytes` was `null`?

Comment: I also tried with  UnitywebRequest.Post  without successfull.. and yes, i need to correct also the "OK" returning value ... using same code, with other web service in my code, without passing byteData , it works...